# passing values present in one user control to another using VB

Tags: controls

i have a user control with a text box and i need to access the value entered in this text box in a label present in another user control. How do i do that in vb.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create a shared event in the first user control (UserControl1):

```
Friend Shared Event GetTextBoxText(ByVal myString As String)
```

you can then raise this event with a button on (UserControl1)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'raise the event with the text from the text box
    RaiseEvent GetTextBoxText(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

on your second user control (UserControl2) add a handler to the event  in your Constructor :

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    'this will let us handle the event from (UserControl1)
    AddHandler UserControl1.GetTextBoxText, AddressOf SetLabelText

End Sub

Private Sub SetLabelText(ByVal myString As String)
    Label1.Text = myString
End Sub
```

now whenever you click the button on (UserControl1) the text will be displayed in the label on UserControl2

you could also add the event handler on any control and respond to GetTextBoxText event

Comment: is there an easier way to do this? I have a lot of values to pass from many usercontrols to one main usercontrol. With your method, I would have to create a handler and a sub for each and every value I would like to pass.