# Passing Values from Multiple UserControls

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

Note: Similar Question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360385/passing-values-present-in-one-user-control-to-another-using-vb).

How can I pass values from multiple User Controls? The question in the link above provides an answer however I find the answer very tedious in my situation and there is a delay in passing of the values. (I have to cycle to and from UserControl1 and UserControl2 multiple times while in UserControl1 committing a change of a textbox or label to see any passing of values in UserControl2.)

Either way, since I have multiple UserControls in which each has many textboxes, labels, and comboboxes, I would very much not like having to create separate Sub Routines and EventHandlers for each and every control with a value that I would like to pass.

Is there a better way? I was thinking something like...

```
'In UserControl10
 Dim UserControl1 As New UserControl1
 Dim UserControl2 As New UserControl2
 Dim UserControl3 As New UserControl3

 UC10Label1.Text = UserControl1.Label1.Text
 UC10TextBox1.Value = UserControl2.TextBox1.Value
 UC10ComboBox1.Text = UserControl3.ComboBox1.SelectedItem
```

The code above obviously does not work the way I would imagine, how can I achieve something similar with the least amount of code?

Edited: I have multiple custom UserControls in which I use as 'views'. In each UserControl there are labels, textboxes, & comboboxes. I have a Panel1 in which on a triggered event, will display a UserControl(1-9) in the panel; each UserControl is displayed one at a time and is contingent on an event. I want to be able to pass values from each UserControl(1-9) to UserControl10's labels, textboxs, or comboboxs etc..

Comment: "How can I pass values from multiple User Controls?"  That question is all but meaningless.  What is it that you actually want to do?  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve.  Keep in mind that a user control is just a control so they get treated like any other control.  There's no magic way to get multiple data items from a user control.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry for not being clear. I have edited my question. Hopefully it is clearer if not I apologize for my lack of description.. (new to vb)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the last three lines aren't in a Sub. They're probably not working because they're executing before the form has been shown.

If you want to update them automatically in your program, you should put them in a sub, but suspend the form layout while they're updating and then resume layout when the code has finished. Like this

```
Private Sub UpdateUserControls()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    UC10Label1.Text = UserControl1.Label1.Text
    UC10TextBox1.Value = UserControl2.TextBox1.Value
    UC10ComboBox1.Text = UserControl3.ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Depending on when you want to update these controls, you can do it each time the form is shown by placing the above `Sub` in the Form's `.Shown` event.

Or you could do it automatically every so often by placing it in a Timer's `.tick` event.

Or you could choose to update them at certain points in your program by placing the sub somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to incorporate something similar based on your answer and got it to work.